# Sending binary data with Indy through TCP\IP, how?

Tags: delphi, tcp, indy, tcpclient

How to send a binary data with Indy components? Which of them is most suitable for this task? I've tried to use `TIdTcpClient` but it allows only to send strings.

I've found one reponce for that problem [here](http://delphigroups.info/2/2/512953.html) but I don't get it.
It says about method `Write(TIdBytes)`, but the answer is not clear for me. Does he meant Write to some instance of `TIdBytes`, and how to connect that instance with `TIdTcpClient`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The page you cite doesn't reproduce the messages very well. Here's what Remy really wrote:

> SendCmd() is designed for textual commands/parameters only. You would have
>   to send the binary data after SendCmd() exited, and the server would have to
>   read the binary data after sending a response back to the client. For
>   example:
>
> --- client ---
>
> ```
> begin
>   IdTCPClient1.SendCmd('DoIt', 200);
>   // send binary data, such as with Write(TStream) or Write(TIdBytes)...
> end;
> ```

The `Write` methods he was talking about are members of the `TIdIOHandler` class. Your `TIdTCPConnection` object has an instance of that class in its `IOHandler` property, and indeed that's what the `SendCmd` function uses to send its string.

The notation `Write(TIdBytes)` means to use the `Write` method that accepts a `TIdBytes` parameter for its input.

If the binary data is already in a stream or a dynamic array of bytes, then you can pass one of those directly to the `Write` method. There's also the `WriteFile` method that will send an entire external file if you provide the file's name. If you use the stream version, then you have the option of including the stream's length automatically.

If you don't have your data in one of those structures already, then you can either write the data piecemeal with the `Write` methods that accept variously sized integer types, or you can copy your data into a `TMemoryStream` and then pass that to `Write`.

Comment: Thanks Rob, the page confused me due to its formating. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Write is a method (or whatever it is called in Delphi) of TCPClient. Here's working code of what you want to do: http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/l/aa012004a.htm. Should get you up & running in no time :)

Comment: Actually, that's *not* working code. At least not for Indy 10. `Write` is not a method of `TIdTCPClient` anymore.

Comment: Thank you Mike, the problem is that I do not have such method in my Indy version for the TIdTcpClient...also the documentation for Indy doest say about those methods... I belive that example which you have given is quite old and not up to date.

Comment: I did not mean you could copy & paste the code, but I personally found it very helpful to write my own code (C++ Builder 2009). Oh well.